# Show Hide Div if element class loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the div if another div class is loaded.
Show `nanobar` only if `selected` class is loaded, in other case `nanobar` will become hidden

css code sample:

```
.nanobar {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fef9c7;
  border:1px solid #fce181;
  color:#333;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  display:none;
}
```

HTML code sample:

```
<div class="nanobar">
<span>Content</span>
</div>
<div id="category_container" class="content-padding {if $category} selected{/if}"> </div>
```

any help in this regards will be appreciated.

Comment: What prevents you from doing what you want? What did you try?

Comment: I trying with this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: Ok, so... what prevents you from using the samples of this page? 
To be clear: on this site, we don't code a whole feature for you for free, we help you to find and fix your bugs. If there is no code, then, there is no solution. You can't just come here and say "i want to do that, how to do that?". You have to show your buggy code and asks why it doesn't work.

Comment: @sjahan I'm a beginner, if I know I will not ask for help...

Comment: I totally understand you are a beginner. The thing is: even though you are a beginner, this is not a place where you can ask for someone else to do your job/homework. You can show your code and ask why this does not work, but you cannot ask to code others to write code instead of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code checks if the second `div` has a `selected` class. If so, the first `div` will be displayed, otherwise the first `div` stays hidden.

```js
let divElements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

if (divElements[1].classList.contains("selected")) {
  divElements[0].classList.replace("hide", "show");
} else {
  divElements[0].classList.replace("show", "hide");
}
```

```css
.nanobar {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fef9c7;
  border:1px solid #fce181;
  color:#333;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
  
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nanobar hide">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="apple jason selected hide">
  <p>Jason</p>
</div>
```

**Note:** Removed the display property from `nanobar` class and made it into it's own class. Makes it easier to hide and show an element, as well as being able to reuse it for other elements.

You can read more about `classList` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Nice, but they're actually trying to hide the 'nanobar' and show it only if the other div has the class called "selected". The best way to test this is probably with `classList.contains()` instead of `className=` in order to allow for more than one class on the element. I also think selecting by tagName (like `.querySelectorAll("div")`) can be a bit fragile, meaning that if another div gets added, it could break your code. Just my thoughts.

Comment: If you don't fully understand the question get some clarification by asking questions in the comments. This will help you write a good answer and will also help the OP edit the question to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

First check if you can find selected class:

```
var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
```

Then check if this variable has more then one element.

```
if (selected.length < 1) {

// Hide your nanobar

} else {
// Show it
}
```

This is not the full solution, if you still have troubles, ask in comments.

Comment: Or if you only want to detect the 'selected' class on that particular div, `if(document.getElementById("category_container").classList.contains("selected")){ document.getElementsByClassName("nanobar")[0].style.display = "block"; }`. Elements have a `classList` property that has a `contains` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). The `getElementsByClassName` method (of the document object, in this case) returns a NodeList, and we use `[0]` to get the first (and possibly only) node from the list (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Comment: Well, your right but if it has to be specific I would just use the id category_container and check if it has the selected class.

Comment: That's what I did :) I was just explaining how the method works (and linking to honorable MDN) for the OP because they said they are new.